# Info from text file, parsed in the code, not being stored into the linked list

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

I have this function that opens, reads, and closes a text file:

```
void readDataFile()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("AssignmentOneInput.txt", "r"); //opens AssignmentOneInput.txt for reading
    char buffer[100];
    char *insertName;
    char *id;

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp);
        insertName = strtok(buffer, ",");
        id = strtok(NULL, ",");
        insertNode(insertName, id); //function right here is supposed to input information
                                    //into the linked list
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

This is my insert function:

```
void insertNode(char *insertName, char *id)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    int intId = atoi(id);

    strcpy(temp->name, insertName);
    temp->id = intId;
    temp->next = head; //rest of the new list is entirety of the current list
    head = temp; //head of the new list is the element being inserted
}
```

I read information in from a text file. I use strtok to parse the information into tokens and store them into their respective variables. Then, I call insertNode at the end of the `while (!feof(fp))` loop to store each line of information into the linked list. However, the information does not get stored.

Whenever I call insertNode in my main function and run through it the information gets stored into the linked list with no problem.

So what I am thinking now is, either the parsing is affecting the information from being stored or something is wrong with my insertNode function.

Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: I don't get your exact problem?? You say things work as expected and is your doubt how? Please re-frame your question and ask what you exactly want

Comment: A person reading your question has no idea what you are talking about. Please make it clear. Also, do you have a [duplicate account](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28390829/inserting-a-name-and-numbers-to-end-of-linked-list)?

Comment: @CoolGuy, no. I do not own that account. This is my only one.

Comment: Ok. Try `int intId;sscanf(" %d",&intId);` instead of `int intId = atoi(id);` and `while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp);)` instead of `while (!feof(fp))` and remove the `fgets` inside the loop body. Also, check the return values of `strtok` and `malloc`.

Comment: @Gopi, 
    `case 1:
                    printf("Enter the name you wish to add: \n");
                    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &insertName);
                    printf("Enter the ID associated with %s: \n", insertName);
                    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &id);
                    insertNode(insertName, id);
                    break;`

When I enter the information manually, it works. However, when I add the `insertNode` function at the end of the `while (!feof(fp))` loop of `readDataFile` then display it, there's nothing.

Comment: @RaffertyHui Do one thing.. Before passing the values to `insertNode()` API print the values being passed in that way you are sure that right values are passed. If they are proper then we will see what migh tbe wrong. Please don't use feof() to check for the EOF use `while(fgets(...) != NULL)`

Comment: @CoolGuy, I tried your changes and the program no longer runs. I am using CodeBlocks for this if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Gopi, Yes, I am getting the output that I want: http://i.imgur.com/bP11kJK.png.

Comment: @RaffertyHui Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @Gopi. Yeah... It's fine now. I made a huge mistake in my main function. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes to your existing code

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL)
{
    insertName = strtok(buffer, ",");
    id = strtok(NULL, ",");
    if(insertName != NULL && id != NULL)
    insertNode(insertName, id);                                 
}
```